# How can I add random color to faces?

Tags: color

I've created this complex mesh, but I don't know how to assign colors to the single faces of the mesh. One face is blue, another red and another green etc. I've seen people using the color ramp, but it doesn't work. How can I make it work?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to go about it, depending on your project's needs, but here's one simple trick:

Enter into *Edit Mode*, select all with <kbd>A</kbd>, unwrap your geometry with <kbd>U</kbd> *> Lightmap Pack*. Then, make the shader below. To get the "rainbow" look of the *ColorRamp* in my example, you can set both colors to something red-ish, and choose the *HSV/Far* mode. Or you can prepare a ramp with colors you want.

[image]

This tends to clump similar colors into relatively large groups, but you can play with the UVs as you wish:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, i was searching this method for days...

Comment: This is a neat trick!

Answer (score 11):

Here is a solution that uses **Geometry Nodes** (requires Blender **3.0**).

[image: random colored faces with geo nodes]

In the *Geometry Nodes Editor*, a random value is assigned to each face. It's a custom attribute named *face_random* in this example. In the side panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) of the *Geometry Nodes Editor*, you need to switch the *Attribute Domain* to `Face` to assign the value to the faces. The *Name* value here (`Face RNG`) is just the label for the attribute as shown in the *Geometry Nodes* modifier settings.

In the *Geometry Nodes* modifier settings, you specify the actual name of the random value attribute. Set *Output Attributes > Face RNG* to `face_random`. This value here should also appear as a column in the *Spreadsheet*. Usually, it's the last one.

In the *Shader Editor*, enter this value (`face_random`) for the *Attribute* node to get each face's random number. With a *ColorRamp* node you can convert the random value to a color.

Comment: This is gold, thank you so much! Is there a way to randomize duplicate objects so they don't have the same random patterns?

Comment: You're welcome :) For different objects, just create a group input slot for the *Seed* of the *Random Value* node (drag the input to the empty group input slot). Then you can assign every object a different *Seed* value in the modifier settings that will create different random values.