# Random Emission Value Per Face

Tags: emission, random

I followed the guide here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/255013/164211 to create random colours preach individual face. I now want to be able to control the emission strength in the same way. I tried duping the attribute and connecting to emission but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you add it to the output attributes in the modifier panel?

Comment: No. Thank you @scurest!